# Gulp watch very strange: multiple run

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I encountered a very strange problem gulp watch.

I have the disk D, which is a section of the hard disk drive of my computer, and E, which is a flash drive.

Each of the discs is file test.txt:

> D:\test\test.txt
>
> E:\test\test.txt

I also have the following gulpfile.js:

```
    gulp.task('test', function()
    {
        gulp.watch('D:/test/test.txt', function (event) {
            console.log('D');
            console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
        })
        gulp.watch('E:/test/test.txt', function (event) {
            console.log('E');
            console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
        })
    });
```

I run gulp and changed E:/test/test.txt...it's okay!

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O7hG.jpg)

and changed D:/test/test.txt...WTF!?

[Image 2](http://imgur.com/473Yi8C)

Why does my code is executed multiple times? Moreover, the number of his accomplishments each time unknown. I noticed this problem yesterday, then when you change files on the disk D code ran 6 times.

P.S Sorry, this is google translate, I very bad speaking English :(

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm ... I found how to fix this problem, but it seems to me that this is a bug. If gulpfile.js test.txt and are on one disc, then there is no error, if different - there. As soon as I moved to drive D gulpfuile.js code became repeated when changing E: \ test \ test.txt